# General rule for CG shift margins and possible databases for existing aircraft

Tags: aircraft-design, weight-and-balance

I am currently working on a weight and balance problem focused mostly on loading operations, and I want to add a new feature that compares the calculated CG travel and those of existing aircraft. Do any of you know where I may find such information or if there is a general rule depending on design and aircraft type?

I already looked in Jane's and no such information is available and aircraft flight manuals usually include only the CG limits, not its average excursion.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about the calculated CG travel in flight due to fuel burn? Or possibly the the typical standard deviation of loads for an aircraft compared to loads of other aircraft types? Or perhaps the %MAC length from forward limit to aft limit of a given aircraft to other aircraft?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "average excursion"...  Nobody keeps records of an aircraft's loaded CG beyond the end of the day.  If a form is created showing the calculation, it is discarded some time after the plane lands safely.  As long as there is no crash and the CG is in limit, the actual CG data for that flight is lost to the sands of time.  What actual "problem" are you working on?

Comment: "... that compares the calculated CG travel and those of existing aircraft." this sentence makes no sense.